# Selecionar e calcular colunas - SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Olá...

```
//selecionar valores da tabela:

    public Cursor IMC(){
            Cursor cursor;
            String[] campos =  {"SELECT (peso/(altura*altura)) FROM medidas WHERE codigo = (SELECT codigo FROM medidas ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1)"};

            db = banco.getReadableDatabase();

            cursor = db.query("medidas", campos, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor!=null){
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            db.close();
            return cursor;
        }
```

No SQLExpert o SELECT buscando só uma coluna ou uma operação simples como peso+altura dá certo, porém essa no código acima retorna 0. Já constatei que está criando o banco e salvando os valores.

```
//mostrar o resultado do SELECT em um TextView
public void resultadoIMC() {

                BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
                Cursor cursor = crud.IMC();


                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtresultado_imc);

                tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(0))));


            }
```

Neste código não retorna valor nenhum, mesmo alterando o SELECT para buscar o valor de uma única coluna (No SQLExpert o SELECT funciona).

Alguém tem alguma ideia do q está errado???

Answer (score 1):

```
//você precisa abrir a conexão antes
db = banco.getReadableDatabase();

//salvando a query antes. Eu NÃO conferi se a query está correta
//só coloquei a maneira certa de fazer um SELECT
String query =  "SELECT (peso/(altura*altura)) FROM medidas WHERE codigo = (SELECT codigo FROM medidas ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1)";

//usando rawQuery, que é o correto
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
```